# Rails redirect to controller/action loses all model errors

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, redirect, model

My use case is simple, in a page called `dashboard/incomes` I display a form to update a record of type `IncomeSetting`.

```
#income-setting-form
  h4 Income Settings
  p Please set your Income Settings using the form below.

  = render 'income_settings/form'
```

This generates the form to edit this type of obejct:

```
= simple_form_for @income_setting do |f|

  = f.hidden_field :user_id

  = f.error_notification

  .form-group
    = f.label :amount
    = f.input_field :amount, required: true, class: 'form-control'
    = f.error :amount, id: 'amount_error'

  = f.association :income_frequency_type, label: 'Frequency:', collection: IncomeFrequencyType.order('id ASC'), include_blank: false, wrapper_html: { class: 'form-group' }, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

  .form-group
    = f.label :start_date
    = f.input_field :start_date, required: true, as: :string, class: 'form-control datepicker'
    = f.error :start_date, id: 'start_date_error'

  = f.association :savings_rate_type, label: 'Savings Rate:', collection: SavingsRateType.order('name ASC'), include_blank: false, wrapper_html: { class: 'form-group' }, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

  .form-group
    = f.label :description
    = f.input_field :description, required: true, class: 'form-control'
    = f.error :description, id: 'amount_error'

  button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block type='submit' Save
```

To keep things RESTful and easy to maintain, I've decided that all actions for `IncomeSetting` objects will be kept in the `income_settings_controller.rb` file.

```
  def update
    if @income_setting.update(income_setting_params)
      redirect_to dashboard_income_path, notice: 'Your Income Setting was saved successfully updated.'
    else
      redirect_to controller: 'dashboard', action: 'income'
    end
  end
```

Do you see where the validation fails, I redirect to the dashboard? If I put a breakpoint there, I can see that the model `@income_setting` **does** have the validation errors there - but just as the controller redirects the model errors are lost?

Any suggestions on how to persist those errors so they actually display by the time the `render 'income_settings/form` is called?

Comment: By design. Redirection discards state. You need to render, not redirect.

Comment: @meager: If I do a render, I'd need to instantiate all of the other instance variables I create in `dashboard#incomes` here in a completely unrelated controller... is there no other way?

Comment: No, this is an extremely common pattern in Rails; you render on error, and redirect on success. This is how virtually every single one of your "create" and "edit" actions should work. If you want an arguably "better" way, do the create via AJAX, and never leave your `dashboard#index` view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to render `dashboard/income` instead of redirecting in the error condition. Since you're sending the form request to a separate controller, you may have to repeat/share setup logic for rendering that page:

```
def update
  if @income_setting.update(income_setting_params)
    redirect_to dashboard_income_path, notice: 'Your Income Setting was saved successfully updated.'
  else
    # additional setup may be necessary
    render 'dashboard/income'
  end
end
```

Comment: If I do a render, I'd need to instantiate all of the other instance variables I create in `dashboard#incomes` here in a completely unrelated controller... is there no other way?

Comment: You could render a view that requires only the data you want to instantiate, if you need to render the dashboard/income template you must instantiate all that the template needs. You can use a private method to do that if you don't want duplicated code, just call that private method inside the normal action and before the template render

Comment: if the controller is "completely unrelated", then, why do you have a relationship right there? Maybe you have to think about some redesign.